# Load pretrained model with explicitly set devices

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've tried to load the pretrained model from one article, but i can't do this becuse i have one GPU-system, but in model it is is explicitly set to use gpu:0 and gpu:1. What can I do to load this model on my pc? 
I have ubuntu, python3.7, cuda10, tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use gpu:0 only at every place since it has only one gpu. Also, as the code is written to use mutiple GPUs, it needs to be changed at every place where it is configured for multi level processing (data or function). Please refer below for more information on GPU usage:

https://jhui.github.io/2017/03/07/TensorFlow-GPU/